# Freemarker JSPTaglib issue while upgrading to Spring Boot 3 and java 17

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I initially started migrating from Spring MVC to Spring Boot 2 I was facing issue related freemarker JspTagLib
That got solved by doing some workaround.

```
<#assign security=JspTaglibs["http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"]/>

<@security.authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
    <@security.authentication property="principal.username"/>
</@security.authorize>
```

Referred: https://vorba.ch/2018/spring-boot-freemarker-security-jsp-taglib.html

Above code is working fine Spring Boot 2

Now I am upgrading Spring Boot 3 then its not working.
Thing which I have added for working in Spring Boot 2, In Boot 3 class field(TaglibFactory) removed.

```
freeMarkerConfigurer.getTaglibFactory().setClasspathTlds(…);
```

Could you please help here?

Comment: Hello, did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for spring to remove getTaglibFactory() is that freemarker 2.3.32 use the javax namespace not the Jakarta EE Namespace. It exist an resolved issue for that [FREEMARKER-218](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FREEMARKER-218). It is solved but it is unknown then version 2.3.33 is released. Maybe then spring brings the getTaglibFactory() method back.